# STM32 HAL Calling HAL_UART_Transmit from another file other than main.c

Tags: stm32, uart, hal, stm32cubemx

I am trying to call HAL_UART_Transmit() from my custom SA145.c file, which causes the error: identifier huart1 us undefined. huart1 is declared as extern in main.c.
How to call HAL_UART_Transmit() from the file other than main.c

Answer (score 0):

> error: identifier huart1 us undefined.

> huart1 is declared as extern in main.c.

Something needs to be declared as `extern` in a file where it is, to use an everyday word, "borrowed".

But it needs to *actually exist* (ie, not be `extern`) is *some* file.  Otherwise the linker will find only attempts to *use* it, but will never actually find an "it" to use.

At the same time, you may not really want to be calling the basic serial function from a lot of places, but may rather want to wrap it in something appropriate to *why* you are calling it, eg, to send data to a peripheral, or to create a debug printout, etc.  Then you can keep the argument in just one file and not need to share it.

Comment: It is declared as an extern in SA145.h file. It complies fine throws linking error as below. HAL headers included in SA145.h 
**.\test_sample.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol huart1 (referred from SA145.o)**
I want to send the data to peripheral.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't focusing on the fact that this is as link error.   See edits